# Full Calendar (jQuery) - Event color is not the same as in legend

Tags: jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

I colorized events in Full Calendar depending on some data from my DB. In my FullCalendarFeed function I assign CSS class to every event. 
And then in CSS file I assign background-color property to every of these classes. Everything looks perfect except `background-color: black` property. Results you can see below that black in legend is not the same as in calendar.

In legend (below calendar) and in calendar I use the same CSS class. In Firefox console (F12) I can't see any opacity or other property that could change the colors, when click on event to check background-color it is RGB(0,0,0). Other colors look OK.

Have anyone meet similar problem?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On some views (like agenda-week), there is a `.25` opacity overlay element.

It's located at `.fc-event-container > .fc-event > .fc-bg` and the class responsible is:

```css
.fc-time-grid-event .fc-bg {
    z-index: 1;
    background: #fff;
    opacity: .25;
    filter: alpha(opacity=25);
}
```

Override the class with something like:

```css
#mycalendar .fc-time-grid-event .fc-bg {
    background: none;
}
```

Make sure you test to make sure things look OK afterwards, though. It may be serving some purpose.

The alternative is to add the overlay to your legend as well.

Comment: Tommorow I will check it in office. I was looking for some opacity as mentioned above but couldn't find any :/  Probably you right :)

Comment: In my verion  FullCalendar v1.6.2 it is in property: `.fc-event-vert .fc-event-bg`. Just for future readers. Thanks...